# pythonでchdirするとFileNotFoundErrorが出る

Tags: python, csv

現在python でcsvファイルを読み込みたいのですが、以下のerrorが出て先へ進めません。。
対処法を教えてください

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
#カレントディレクトリの確認↑

import pandas as pd
os.chdir("c:/home2/1851068h/Desktop/python/0000.csv")
```

```
FileNotFoundError             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-9f3ecf581f47> in <module>
----> 1 os.chdir("c:/home2/1851068h/Desktop/python/0000.csv")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/home2/1851068h/Desktop/python/0000.csv'
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

`os.chdir()`はディレクトリを移動するものなので、ファイルを指定してはいけません。
`0000.csv`の部分を外して、ディレクトリのパス名だけを指定してください。

それから`os.getcwd()`で表示されたパス名と`os.chdir()`に指定するパス名の釣り合い("c:"が付くか付かないか)が取れていないのですが、大丈夫でしょうか？
その辺は合わせるようにした方が良いと思われます。

[Python入門 ディレクトリ操作の基本 (1/3)](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1910/25/news021.html)
上記記事の「カレントディレクトリの取得」を項を参照。

---

コメントの件は、こちらが関係しているかもしれません。
[jupyter notebookでcsvファイルを読み込む方法](https://qiita.com/ishiken3/items/71f1d354b3119ae6c09f)

> 注意点としては、jupyterからuploadでファイルを取り込むという点。
>
> デスクトップに置いたファイルのパスを指定してもcsvを取り込むことはできないのでここで数時間ハマりました。

ただし付いているコメントにはこんなのもあります。

> 絶対パスで指定すればローカルのどの場所にあるcsvも取り出せますよ

Comment: os.chdir("/home2/1851068h/Desktop/python")とプログラムを変更して作動しました。次にimport csv
csvfile = open('0000.csv')
for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
    print(row)  とプログラムを書きましたが                                                                         FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0000.csv'とerrorが出てしまいます。。

Comment: コメント欄では改行とか書式に従った表示は出来ないので、質問記事を編集して追記するか、内容が別の現象なので新たに質問を起こすかしてください。ちなみに、その場所にそのファイルが存在していることや、読み取り可能なことは確認していますか？作成中でセーブしていなかったり、別のエディタでOpen中なので他からアクセス出来ないとかありませんか？